# Try-Catch Problem in c++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am trying queue implementation in c++. During that I am having this problem.

```
void Queue::view() 
{
 int i;
 try
 {
  if(Qstatus==EMPTY)
  {
    UnderFlowException ex = UnderFlowException("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY");
    throw ex;
  }
 }

 i=front;
 cout<<"Queue contains...\n";

 while(i <= rear)
 {
  cout<<queue[i]<<" ";
  i++;
 }
}
```

This gives an error as :

> error: expected ‘catch’ before ‘i’

I think this problem is arises since I doesn't written catch block below try block.
But If want to write the catch block in main(), ( like in this case ), how could I do that?

> Before, that Could I do that? If not Why?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your while loop will run forever unless queue[i] increments i (which is unlikely).

Comment: i was about to answer 1st time on SO :) but these multi-core users..

Comment: Another question could be why did you add the `try` block? if it was because you anticipated an exception getting thrown, it seems obvious that the `catch` is missing. But I get the feeling you are not quite aware of what the try catch statements are for, if this is the case you might want to look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Looks cleaner if you write `UnderFlowException ex("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY");`

Comment: A view method probably shouldn't throw anything in the first place... Why would it be an error to want to output an empty queue? Better reserve UnderFlowError for operations where non-empty queue is a precondition (pop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`catch` block must follow the `try` block. If you want the `catch` to be in `main` - that's where the `try` has to be too. You can `throw` everywhere, doesn't have to be inside a `try` block within the same function.

It should be something like this:

```
void Queue::view() 
{
 int i;
 if(Qstatus==EMPTY)
 {
    UnderFlowException ex = UnderFlowException("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY");
    throw ex;
 }

 i=front;
 cout<<"Queue contains...\n";

 while(i <= rear)
  cout<<queue[i]<<" ";
}
/// ...
int main()
{
    Queue q;
    try{
       q.view();
    }
    catch(UnderFlowException ex)
    {
        /// handle
    }
    catch (...)
    {
     /// unexpected exceptions
    }
    // follow the success/handled errors
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to remove the `try` block. A `try` block always goes with a `catch`.

```
void Queue::view() 
{
    int i;
    if(Qstatus==EMPTY)
    {
        ex = UnderFlowException("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY");
        throw ex;
    }

    i=front;
    cout<<"Queue contains...\n";

    while(i <= rear)
        cout<<queue[i]<<" ";
}
```

You can then include a `try/catch` construct in your `main`.

```
int main()
{
    Queue queue;
    try
    {
        queue.View()
    }
    catch(UnderFlowException ex)
    {
        //handle ex
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All try blocks need at least one associated catch block. You should remove the try block if you have no intentions of handling any exceptions here. Exceptions can be (and usually should be!) thrown outside of a try block.

Answer (score 0):

Make your code catch and rethrow the exception, like this:

```
try
{
 if(Qstatus==EMPTY)
 {
   UnderFlowException ex = UnderFlowException("\nQUEUE IS EMPTY");
   throw ex;
 }
} catch( ... ) {
   throw; // rethrow whatever exception we just catched
}
```

Although you don't even need the `try` block in the first place. Looks like just `throw ex;` would work, since you don't intend to catch it but just throw it.

Comment: caught not catched, and why catch in the first place?

Comment: This try-catch is code bloat, and doesn't do anything but potentially slow the program down. Removing the try block is a better solution.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Well that's **how** he can do it, although there does not seem to be a point in doing it.

Comment: A `view` method probably shouldn't throw anything in the first place... Why would it be an error to output an empty queue?

Comment: @UncleBens: Well I'm not cuestioning his logic, though I disagree with it... Make that a comment on the OP question so he notices it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
}
catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Catch must be immediately after try. These are the rules.